# Find the following conditional probabilities:

Tags: probability, statistics

A box contains one yellow, two red, and three green balls. Two balls are randomly chosen without replacement. Define the following events:

> A:{One of the balls is yellow }
> B:{At least one ball is red }
> C:{Both balls are green }
> D:{Both balls are of the same color}

Find the following conditional probabilities:
(a)$P(B|A^c)=$
(b)$P(B|D^c)=$
(c)$P(D|C^c)=$

I got $A: 1/3$ (1/6 probability for each draw), $B: 3/5, C: 1/5, D: 4/15$. To find the complements, subtract the probabilities from $1: A^c: 2/3, D^c: 11/15,C^c = 4/5$ Then use the conditional probability formula to find the conditional probabilities. I got $P(B|A^c) = 3/5, P(B|D^c)=3/5$, and $P(D|C^c)=4/15$. However, the last two weren't correct, and I'm unsure about whether the first one is correct. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: You calculated $\Pr(A), \Pr(B), \Pr(C), \Pr(D), \Pr(A^C), \Pr(C^C),$ and $\Pr(D^C)$ correctly.  However, we can't determine what you did wrong unless you show us how you calculated $\Pr(B \mid A^C), \Pr(B \mid D^C),$ and $\Pr(D \mid C^C)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial probabilities are correct, but you need to first make a chart, and the chart needs to include frequencies of compound events $YR,YG,RG,RR,GG$ else you will flounder.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
Combo & YR & YG & RG & RR & GG \\ \hline
Frequency & 2 & 3 & 6 & 1 & 3 \\ \hline
A & \bullet &\bullet \\ \hline
B & \bullet & & \bullet & \bullet \\ \hline
C & & & & & \bullet \\ \hline
D & & & & \bullet & \bullet\\ \hline\end{array}$

From here, you should be able to do it on your own ?

Comment: Is the hint clear ?